# No push notification received after upgrade parse sdk to 1.10.2

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have application that implement parse sdk, currently using 1.7.1 version. I want to upgrade to latest sdk (1.10.2) but when i change the sdk, no push notification received. Is there is some code to change or anything else? because i only changed dependency in gradle.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should look at parse documentation..!!

Comment: add code that you have done

Comment: Ya it's working now. I am not sure, but when i try to run in phone not emulator, the notification is received